# pdf byte array read first line

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a pdf byte array and was wondering if there was an easy way to read the first line of text into a variable?

Thanks,
rod

Comment: I have no idea, but I think I'd have more luck asking the people behind iText directly if it's possible with their product.

Comment: From my minimal knowledge of the PDF format, I can tell you that reading the first line of text requires reading/parsing the text first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out "SimpleTextParser" and the rest of the com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser package (or whatever its called in C#-ville).

Note that "The First Line of Text" is a very slippery concept in PDF.  Glyphs are drawn at specific coordinates.  If a given clump of glyphs happens to share a base-line, they're visually on the same line.  If a given shared baseline is the one closest to the top of the page, its the "first".

Oh, and the page might be rotated, throwing everything into a special kind of hell called "matrix math".

There's no particular requirement to write out text in PDF in a logical order.  One could go through and write all the 'a's, then the 'b's, and so forth.  Not bloody likely (or efficient), but perfectly legal.  What IS likely is that all the text in a given font is drawn, followed by all the text in the next font, and so forth.  If the first line of text happens to be in a couple different fonts (bold, italic, etc), you might find it harder than one would expect to locate the proper Line Of Text.  A program might easily iterate through the fonts alphabetically, or store them in a hash map... don't depend on logical order to match "the order things are drawn".  Sooner or later (probably sooner) you will be in for a rude shock.

I suggest you go read an iText FAQ or two.  Your question betrays a level of ignorance that is easily cured with a little effort on your part.  If nothing else, the freely available chapters from [iText In Action](http://www.itextpdf.com/book/) (and its cornucopia of samples) should prove illuminating.

Comment: And all that is assuming the text in your PDF really is text.  It could be unmapped glyphs (with no 'collection of squiggles' to 'character' information), a bitmap, or line art.  If any of those is the case, you're pretty much stuck with OCR (which should at least give you the text in a rational order).  If you can select, copy, and paste it from Acrobat/Reader, chances are you can get the text out with iText.  If not, you're pretty much doomed.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] pdf;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf)));
String firstLine = in.readLine();
in.close();
```

Comment: That is probably not what he is looking for :)

Comment: Oh... maybe I should retag it to "Java" so my answer fits better :)

Comment: Oh 2! I thought he wanted to read the first line of the byte array to determine the PDF version... Not the first line of the Text of the PDF.

Comment: :) well... his question isn't very precise